# Where to put the apostrophe in a sentence where the name contains an appositive?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, appositives

If the name in the sentence contains an appostive, does it change the location of the apostrophe?

For example:

> John Smith's car is red

Now imagine I have an appostive to that subject that comes before the possession object of the sentence, would the apostrophe's location be:

> John Smith's - my very father - car is red

or

> John Smith - my very father's - car is red

That question came up in my mind after listening to an american podcast where the host used a sentence in the latter manner.

Comment: Is my very father mi proprio padre? If so, the English is: my own father. In which case, you need to change  your sentence. My own father's car is red. El carro de mi proprio padre es rojo.

Comment: And an English speaker likely wouldn't normally include the "own', "My father" determines who is being discussed with enough particularity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possessive with Two Nouns.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194073/possessive-with-two-nouns) See also ["Nikki's and Alice's cars" vs. "Nikki and Alice's cars"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-cars-vs-nikki-and-alices-cars) on ELU.

Comment: You might want to consider how many Anglophones are quite happy to write [*my wife and **I's***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+wife+and+i%27s%22) *[jointly-owned thing]*. The possessive apostrophe can apply to *any* length/complexity of antecedent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _My wife's and my house/car/cats_ is what I would say. _My father's and brother's cars_ is ambiguous.

Comment: Any structure that paints you into a corner screams for a rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Yosef: my point about *...and **I's*** was just to show that even though in isolation it looks a bit ridiculous, *lots* of perfectly competent writers have used it. If ***'s*** is capable of handling a list ending in ***I***, it can handle *anything*. Up to and including "bracketed asides" and interjections. You ***can*** always rephrase to avoid things you don't like, but you don't ***have*** to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This question isn't about a list. It's about a noun and an appositive, which means they both have the same referent, so this comment and the possible dupes don't apply. The grammar could be different for all the OP knows.

Comment: @gotube: I disagree. *Everything* (including any appositive) before the possessive ***'s*** can fall within its scope. And the fact that even if all that preceding text ends with the word ***I***, we *still* append and articulate ***'s*** should be taken as proof this is a *very* robust "clitic" that's pretty much impervious to context (it *always* works the same, regardless of the *exact* context).

Comment: Why is everyone trying to fix what is not grammatical in English??

Comment: "My very father" is a mistranslation of *mi proprio padre*: my own father. The name does not contain an appositive. An appositive is this: "my father, John Smith, etc."

Answer (score 2):

Your example has the appositive NP as a supplement (as opposed to an integrated one). A supplementation consisting of one NP as anchor and another as supplement may have either multiple or singular marking.

> *John Smith's, my father's, car is red.*
>
> *John Smith, my father's car is red.*

The multiple-marking version is preferred in writing, probably because it allows the supplement to be set off by paired commas (or dashes). But it is the singular-marking version that is usually heard.

EDIT: The acceptability of the  above examples is marginal. This is not because of doubts about the punctuation, but because the proper name should be the appositive element, not the head:

> *My father's, John Smith's, car is red*.
>
> *My father, John Smith's car is red.*

Comment: Is this based on your feeling as a native speaker (as my answer is), or can you source this?

Comment: @gotube It's based on intuition reinforced by attested examples cited in H&P's CGEL. The OP's example does sound odd, though it's not because of the punctuation but because the proper name should be the appositive element, not the head. I've added an edit to my answer to support this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to structure that sentence with "John Smith" and "my father" in that order to express possession of the car. It would have to be reworded so that the noun phrase and apposition were *the possessed object*, rather than the possessor with "'s" alone:

> John Smith's **car** -- my father's **car** -- is red.

As to your two examples, the first one is out because you can never say, "my father car". The second one is closer, but doesn't work either because the "my father's" is an adjective phrase, so it cannot be in apposition to "John Smith", which is a noun phrase.

The closest I can come to acceptable is to put possession on *both* nouns:

> *John Smith's -- my father's --(??) car is red.

This doesn't work either in writing or in casual speech. In writing, you need a dash (--) before "my father's", but you cannot have a dash after it (hence the ?? above) because it would visually break up the noun phrase "my father's car". You also can't have just one and not the other.

In speech, there are no punctuation marks, but if you put the possessive on both nouns, it sounds like you're correcting yourself or revising your sentence to begin with "My father's...". A listener would not likely understand the second to be an appositive.

Comment: If this was correct, we'd expect [*My **wife's** and **I's** seafood dinner.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) but nobody says that. There's only one "act of possession" involved, so regardless of whether that possession is by multiple entities, or one entity referred to in multiple ways, ***there's only one possessive apostrophe***.

Comment: The OP's example has the appositive NP as a supplement (as opposed to an integrated one). A supplementation consisting of one NP as anchor and another as supplement may have either multiple or singular marking. Thus we can say "John Smith's, my father's, car" _or_ "John Smith, my father's car". The multiple-marking version is preferred in writing, but in speech it is the singular-marking version that is usually heard.

Comment: @BillJ "John Smith's, my father's, car" or "John Smith, my father's car"" Huh? Those are unacceptable any way you look at it...

Comment: The issue with proper names is that they should really occur as the appositive element, not the head as it does in the OP's example Thus, "my father's", John Smith's, car" and "my father, John Smith's car" would be much preferred.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why do you assert that there's only one possessive apostrophe? What you say is true about *lists* of nouns that collectively possess something, but the question is about an *appositive construction*, not a list, so your answer isn't relevant.  Your conclusion might still be right, but please show that it's true about appositives, and not lists.

Comment: @BillJ "John Smith's, my father's, car"* feels wrong because of the comma between "father's" and "car". *"John Smith, my father's car"* is wrong because it would mean my father's car is named "John Smith", which is not the intent. What do you mean by "usually heard"? I can't imagine a native speaker saying this without stumbling over it, indicating that it's not a good basis for describing what's correct.

Comment: However you punctuate it, and regardless of whether you repeat the clitic, *John Smith, my father's car"* is barely "English", so it's hardly worth getting too dogmatic about "correct punctuation". *But* I maintain that to the extent we accept that sequence of words in the first place, possessive ***'s*** is a "word" in it's own right. If the speaker *knows* he's going to add a second noun, as in *"John (my uncle)'s car broke down today"* he wouldn't normally apostrophize *John's.* I see no reason to change that position for any other more exotic contexts involving multiple nouns.

Comment: As I said earlier, a proper name should occur as the appositive element, not the head. That being the case, there is nothing wrong with either of these: "my father's", John Smith's, car" /  "my father, John Smith's car".  The multiple marking is preferred in writing, the single-marking common is speech.